# Jenkins declarative pipeline appears to be executing a bash script twice

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a stage in my Jenkins pipeline that does the following:

```
stage('nose tests') {
        steps {
            timeout(45) {
                wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', additionalOptions: '', assignedLabels: '', displayName: 99,
                      displayNameOffset: 0, installationName: 'Xvfb', screen: '']) {
                    sh "bin/run-ci-tests.sh"
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                junit '**/nosetests.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```

The bash script `bin/run-ci-tests.sh` sets up a venv, updates requirements, starts up various dependencies and then runs nosetests.

The bash script also tries to clean up after itself, by killing various child processes.  This has turned out to be a little more complicated in the Jenkins context, as the Jenkins slave process is part of the process group, so I can't just kill by PGID.

While troubleshooting the clean up, I noticed that there appear to be two PIDs saying their command is `bin/run-ci-tests.sh".  It would not be great if this is actually getting run twice...

```
ubuntu@jenkins3-exec02:~$ ps aux | grep run-ci-tests.sh
jenkins  10797  0.0  0.0  11212  1644 ?        S    17:22   0:00 bash     bin/run-ci-tests.sh
jenkins  10810  0.0  0.0  11204   672 ?        S    17:22   0:00 bash bin/run-ci-tests.sh
ubuntu   12114  0.0  0.0  10464   948 pts/0    S+   17:24   0:00 grep --color=auto run-ci-tests.sh
```

Any insight out there on why this might be appearing to be run twice ?

Comment: Jenkins should automatically kill child processes when a build ends. Can you run `ps auxf`, perhaps without grepping, to show the process hierarchy, and see whether the second bash is really separate, or a part of the first bash invocation?

Comment: Any luck with a solution for this issue?